# IIS 7.5 Compression has no effect compared to IIS 6

Tags: performance, iis-7.5, http-compression

I activated the compression feature (dynamic and static) on IIS 7.5.

However, I see sites loading very slowly and I do not feel any compression at all especially for SWF, JPG, CSS, JS and ASPX extensions.

In IIS 6, I used to edit metabase file to add these extensions to compression. Shall I do the same with IIS 7.5?

What is the file I shall edit and which section exactly?

Please, help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no point in adding compression for SWF and JPG as they're already compressed formats.

On IIS7 you shouldn't need to edit the metabase as the options are exposed via the IIS settings for the site

Comment: Thanks for the info, Andy. I think the sites are having a code issue as they are too heavy loading.